# how to choose one image to show in ImageView

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, I want to show one image in ImageView, but I want to give user options to choose from list image (maybe put text somewhere in there).
and maybe save it on firebase database, so when user reopen/restart the app, that image user choose/select before will show somewhere in their profile/activity.
so far I've tried `RadioButton, CheckBox, Spinner`.
and non of them work, maybe I don't know implement it properly.
I'm hoping someone help me solve this, it's help a lot.
thanks.

Comment: Only an ImageView can display images.

Comment: yes I know that, it's called ImageView, not TextView, what I mean is, user can select image from image list (like Spinner, or RadioButton), and when they selected that image, the app gonna upload id, or data, or something like that to firebase, so user can retrieve that data when reopen the app, so they don't need to select again.

Comment: Is that all? And which which of the twenty two necessary steps do you have a problem?

Comment: the problem is I don't know how to upload that image list id/data that user select to firebase, and retrieve that id/data what app reopen.

Comment: That has little to do with the subject of your post.